# Horizontal Menu Styling

Tags: css, padding

I am working on a few websites and having major issues with horizontal menu spacing. One website is daniellesshoes.com (this is a BigCommerce site) another is blog.daniellesshoes.com (this is WordPress)

My issue is this. We make these websites for clients. We want the menu to be purple, and the li's to highlight pink when hovered on. Two issues in that. 1. if the client adds a menu item from the BigCommerce CSS, it will mess up the spacing..

2nd issue is that IE6, 7, 8, and 9 all show pixel differences in spacing and some disable overflow hidden etc etc etc etc

So either 1. I want to get ride of all the style (BigCommerce for some reason comes with 7+ stylesheets all overriding eachother etc ) and redesign my own -the correct way! or 2. Figure out what I have to add to make it look the same on each browser. Lastly, once I get that done, I'd like them to space automatically..

Please view the above mentioned websites and inspect element, then let me know what the heck I should do. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Rules for list-based menus:

1. Use a CSS reset
2. Don't style the `LI` tags (other than position:, display: and float:)
3. Use `display:block` and style the `A`-tags
4. Clear your floats if you're using them

See my tutorial: [`I Love Lists`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

Comment: A more complete and up to date reset CSS: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to space items automatically in CSS is by using `display: table;` and `table-cell` and `table-layout: fixed;`. It works in every modern browser and IE8, as it's CSS2.1 recently supported everywhere.

Check first example of this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aznxD/
Resetting CSS for lists is done by indicating:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

No need for changing `list-style` if you already change the value of `display` for `li`. The 40 other lines of various reset CSS are for other things than lists, that's OT here.

The second example in previous fiddle is for IE6/7, by using sort of `display: inline-block` (see comment in CSS and in the JS left-bottom part of screen) and calculated padding that will depend of the number of items in menu and length of text. That's why items won't space automatically... You can add these specific rules via [conditional comments in a specific stylesheet or around html element with class(es)](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

This is not pixel perfect... but it isn't *that* important: nobody except you will see your site in numerous browsers and their different versions.
Maybe some people will see your site on two browsers, one at work and another one at home. Will they notice that my example is 957px wide and not 960px anymore? Will they care or will they be glad that it's less horrible than most sites designed for "modern browsers" with no care and tests at all for old browsers? (designing for modern browsers isn't a problem, not caring at all for older ones with no fallback *is* a problem)
IMHO your time will be better used at providing media queries in support of Responsive Web Design and maybe Mobile First in a second or third time and removing every unused CSS rule in your CMS if it's bloated: better maintenance in the future and better performance now and in the future.